# Is there a shortcut to format multiple lines of code into one line in VS Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, formatting

I needed a long list of words for a python program in Visual Studio Code, but each word came on a new line, I now have thousands of pasted words and I can't go through each word one by one. Is there a shortcut that can be used here?

Comment: Use find and replace feature using regex, e.g. /n to replace it with a space.

Answer (score 0):

Not actually answering the question (as is customary) but I'd suggest putting the words into a separate file, e.g. `words.txt` and then doing

```
with open('words.txt', 'r') as f:
    words = f.read().splitlines()
```

if that fits your usecase.